# Visual Studio 2010 is crashing/hanging when trying to debug ASP.NET 2.0 site

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I have been experiencing problems with Visual Studio 2010 and debugging.
I have been getting the:

**"Unable to start debugging on the web server. The IIS worker process for the launched URL is not currently running."** error, but it appears VS2010 now doesn't want to function at all and is hanging.

Whenever I try to attach the debugger, it doesn't.
If I try and run the project using the custom URL and letting IIS7 server the web page, the whole IDE is now hanging.

Has anyone had problems with the debugger not attaching, running the project with the debugger causing the above error and/or Visual Studio hanging completely when running the debugger?

I can't even minimise the IDE window and it seems to flicker when I click the button.